# showing that a function with $f(x) - kx$ bounded has a fixed point

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to prove that a continuous function $f$ in $\mathbb{R}$ with $f(x) - kx$ bounded, $k \in ]-1; 1[$ has a fixed point, **i.e $\exists x$ such as $f(x) = x$**

I've tried proving that $f(x) - kx$ has a fixed point using the intermediate value theorem, by using $g(x) = f(x) - kx - x$ but showing this leads me nowhere to proving that $f$ has a fixed point

I don't really know how to proceed, any ideas?

Comment: FYI.  your original wording read, at least to me, the exact opposite of the current one (IE it read that $f$ was bounded and you wanted $f(x)-kx$ to have the fixed point.  I deleted my answer to that question

Answer (score 1):

By hypothesis, there exists $M > 0$ such that for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$-M \leq f(x)-kx \leq M, \quad \text{i.e.} \quad kx-M \leq f(x) \leq kx+M$$

Let
$$x_0=\frac{M}{1-k} \quad \text{and} \quad x_1 = \frac{M}{k-1}$$

You have
$$f(x_0) \leq kx_0 + M = M \left( \frac{k}{1-k} + 1\right) = \frac{M}{1-k} = x_0$$

and $$f(x_1) \geq kx_1 - M = M \left( \frac{k}{k-1} - 1\right) = \frac{M}{k-1} = x_1$$

So you get
$$f(x_0) \leq x_0 \quad \text{and} \quad f(x_1) \geq x_1$$

Now you can apply the IVT to get a fixed point for $f$.

Answer (score -1):

Assume that $f(x)-kx$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}$ for $k\in (-1, 1)$. Then there exists $m, M\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $m\leq f(x)-kx\leq M$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}.$ To show that $f(x)-kx$ has a fixed point in $\mathbb{R}$. Define $g(x)=f(x)-kx-x$, then $g(m)=f(m)-km-m\geq 0$ and $g(M)=f(M)-kM-M\leq 0.$ By IVP, there exists $c\in (m, M)\subset\mathbb{R}$ such that $g(c)=0\Rightarrow f(c)-kc-c=0$. Implies that $f(x)-kx$ has a fixed point.

Comment: That's the problem, I need to show that $f$ has a fixed point, not $f(x) - kx$. As stated in the question, I've already show that $f(x) - kx$ has a fixed point using IVP, but this doesn't help me prove the fact that $f$ has a fixed point